# ORM: Sequelize: Check many to many relationship before inserting an entry to message table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, orm, sequelize.js

I am developing a simple chat application. Everything works fine but I have a question related to data integrity.

This is the schema of the database.

- User HAS MANY chat rooms.
- Chat room HAS MANY users.
- User HAS MANY messages.
- Chat room HAS MANY messages.

[image: db schema]

Let me explain what I am trying to achieve with an example.

```js
    // creates user1
    User.create({})
    // creates user2
    User.create({})
​
    // creates the chat room with id 1
    ChatRoom.create({isGroupChat: false});
​
    // add user 1 to chatroom 1
    UserChatRoom.create({userID: 1, chatRoomID: 1});
​
    // this should work because user 1 is in chat room 1
    Message.create({userID: 1, chatRoomID: 1, seen: false, message: 'test'});
​
    // this works but, logically, it shouldn't work because user 2 is not added to chatroom 1
    // How can I prevent user2 to add a message to chat room 1?
 Message.create({userID: 2, chatRoomID: 1, seen: false, message: 'test'});
```

How can I prevent user2 to add a message to chat room 1?

I wrote this function and it works fine but I wonder if we can tell db to check this relationship before inserting a message(without writing any js logic).

```js
export async function sendMessage({userID, chatRoomID, message}): Promise<Message>{
    // check if user is in that chat room
    const user = await User.findOne(
        {where: {id: userID},
        include: [
            {
                model: ChatRoom,
                where: {id: chatRoomID},
                required: true
            },
        ]
    });
    // if user is in that chat room, create the message
    if(user?.chatRooms){
        return Message.create({message, seen: false, chatRoomID, userID});
    }
    throw new Error(`User ${userID} is not in chat room ${chatRoomID}`);
 }
```

Comment: `findOne()` returns `null` if no records found, and an object if found. Doing `length` check doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes I know. I have actually deleted length check from the original code but forgot to remove it here. Will update it.

Edit: updated

Comment: Wouldn't user.chatRooms be an array? I mean, it could be empty, which means your condition would still run.

Comment: One thing more. `User.findOne()` will return a record even if there is no relationship with passed `chatRoomId`. You have to also pass `required: true` to `join` only if `user_id` exist.

Comment: Any method you would find. It will end up with the same, checking if record with key exist or not. You can use `count`, `findOne` or `instance.hasModel` with where clause. I would prefer `findOne()` with `required:true` in this case though.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated it.